# How to Straight the Image and how to use Bullets in bottom slider I am using react-coverflow Library

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I want to straight the images thumb image and also the bullets  of the [react-coverflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-coverflow) Library Slider.

[image]

i am using this code

```
 <Coverflow width="960" height="500"
    displayQuantityOfSide={2}
    navigation={false}
    enableScroll={true}
    clickable={true}
    active={0}
  >
    <div
      onClick={() => fn()}
      onKeyDown={() => fn()}
      role="menuitem"
      tabIndex="0"
    >
      <img
        src='image/path'
        alt='title or description'
        style={{
          display: 'block',
          width: '100%',
        }}
      />
    </div>
    <img src='image/path' alt='title or description' data-action="http://andyyou.github.io/react-coverflow/"/>
    <img src='image/path' alt='title or description' data-action="http://andyyou.github.io/react-coverflow/"/>
  </Coverflow>
```

Comment: Fix your image it is not appearing correctly. Upload it to imgur.com and then edit your code and paste it in there

Answer (score 0):

You need to use slick slider. I have also faced the same issue and worked for me 
[Slick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick-slider)